# How to access a logged in user from a class based view?

Tags: python, django

How do I access a current logged in user from a class-based view?
In a function-based view we can pass a request parameter but I can't pass a request parameter from a class view.
I have seen ways to do it in the internet but I can't understand it.

my models.py file

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=3500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="uncategorized")
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self.request.user` inside methods of class-based views; as an example:

```
class HomeView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        current_loggedin_user = self.request.user
        # ...
```

Edit (just print the `username`):

```
class HomeView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.user, self.request.user.username) # print user & username
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How do I print his username

Comment: @Rashaad Use `print(self.request.user.username)` inside any method that suits your needs best; In reality, you probably don't want to just print it to the console, right? So, for example, if you want to grab the `username` and use it somehow while listing the items in your `ListView`, you can override `get_queryset` method of `ListView` and use that there.

Comment: I want to just print it in the console and see but it doesn't get printed

Comment: I get this error 
      line 16, in __init__
      print(self.request.user, 
      self.request.user.username)  # print user & 
      username
       AttributeError: 'HomeView' object has no attribute 
       'request'

Comment: Use `get` method instead of `__init__`. That is `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I get this error:   

ValueError at /
The view polls.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.